# Good mapping tools for odd topologies

Tags: map-making, tool-recommendation, 3d-space

I'm looking to host a game that takes place in an asteroid terrarium traveling through interstellar space.  Does anyone know of mapping software for 1) the inside of the asteroid, which resembles the inside of a cylinder and 2) local space around the asteroid which should be three dimensional?

Comment: The inside surface of a cylinder is a rectangle (if the ends are open)

Comment: Right.  For some reason I keep thinking that it's more complicated than that.  Mostly smoothly connecting the long side and plotting points that connect from one point  to the another on the opposite wall but i guess i can treat those as antipodes.  My intuition is that if I treat it like a sphere I'll be off by quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inside the asteroid, if it's along the inside of a cylinder, I suggest going with a traditional dungeon mapping software and just saying that two opposite sides of your map touch (conceptually rolling the map into a tube). [DungeonMapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dungeonmap/?source=directory)

For 3D modeling the asteroid, that can be tricky. 3DS max, as nerre said, is a good tool, but it has a steep learning curve which may not be good for you (on the flip side, may be perfect if you plan to publish later), alternatively, Sketchup as Wyrmwood said is a pretty good one to do easily, but it's tricky to get that organic look in Sketchup. An alternative (if you plan on showing it printed out on paper and aren't 3d printing a model of it) would be to grab some images of asteroids from ESA's Rossetta probe of the comet (since it's got pictures in 360 degrees). It's not quite a cylinder, but its one of the best pictured asteroid-like objects out there. Alternatively, various space agencies have other asteroid pics, and you can try to find one that matches what you want a little better.

Comment: There are pretty good images of Eros available online; that's a smallish asteroid that's almost exactly the shape of a "terrarium" colony: roughly cylindrical, around 2.5 times as long as it is across (I recall it being 4x10 miles, but that could be wrong).  Good photos (and radar maps) are available because Eros periodically passes fairly close to Earth.

Answer (score 1):

For the three dimensional mapping you could use a 3D-renderer like Blender, Maya, 3D-Studio-Max. You would not actually have to render them, you could just type in the coordinates of little placeholder objects and name them so you know what they symbolize. Use the programm and file as a 3d-map. Using sprites or doing a few simple tutorials, you could even use images of what you want to show, and render the scene into pictures.

For the cylinder-inside, the comment above is right, it is just a rectangle. Just be aware that what leaves over the upper border, enters over the lower border at the exact same x coordinate and with the same vector, since you can travel infinitly inside a cylinder, if you walk orthogonally to its rotation axis. (At least I suppose it does rotate to provide artifical gravity, since you want to play in it).

But if you also map the interior with a 3d-tool, I think you could render a map using a 360° degree camera, although you would have to get rid of the perspective if you really want a flat map of the surface.

Anyway, here is a link: [Blender Developer Documentation Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org)

Answer (score 1):

If you can "imagine" a 2d representation, you can "pull" the image into 3d with [sketch up](http://www.sketchup.com/). How you would represent this in a game tool is another matter :) You'd probably be better off to use a 2d representation, using isometric views, but if you really wanted to go down that road, you could use something like [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) or [Panda3d](https://www.panda3d.org/).